# Let an array point to another array with different bounds in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I need to use a library which has following typedef and method:

```
typedef short int SomeArray[3];

void method(SomeArray* arr){//doSomething}
```

In my main code I have a big array and want a smaller array that has exactly the same index values as the bigger array:

```
short int var[5] = {0, 1, 2, 4, 5};
```

I need a variable of type SomeArray, whose [0] = var[1], [1] = var[2], [2] = var[3] to pass it to the test() method. This:

```
short int* intf = &var[1];
```

gives what I need when I access it by intf[?]. But how to convert it into a variable of type SomeArray to be an array with 3 elements? I tried different methods like

```
SomeArray* arr = intf;
SomeArray* arr = (SomeArray*)intf;
SomeArray* arr = &var[1];
```

But either it wont work or the element address of every arr element does not match with the element address (on the position needed) of the bigger array.

Comment: Note that C and C++ are two *very* different languages, which a lot of semantic details differing. If you ask about C++ then please don't tag C as well.

Comment: Also, an array is not a pointer, and a pointer is not an array. Arrays and pointer types are different. An array can *decay* to a pointer to its first element, and pointers can be indexed like arrays (because all array indexing really is pointer arithmetic).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker it gave me errors while compilation, like "cannot convert 'short unsigned int*' to 'short unsigned int (*)[3]" or cannot convert 'short unsigned int**' to 'short unsigned int (*)[3]

Comment: As for possible ways to solve your problems, why not create a new *instance* of `SomeArray`, like e.g. `SomeArray intf;` and then [copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) the needed elements from `var` to `intf`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It need to be dynamically. If I assign an element of var like "var[2] = 3" then a call to arr[1] has to be 3. This is because its a library of an USB device and all changes of the SomeArray pointer are stored live in the device

Comment: Then you simply have to use `short int*`, and can't use your `SomeArray` type. Is there a specific reason you don't want that?

Comment: `SomeArray` is the type "array of three `short int`s", thus  `SomeArray*` is the type "pointer to array of three `short int`s". `intf` has the type "pointer to one `short int`". A pointer to one `short int` is not a pointer to an array of three `short int`s. If you just want a pointer into a larger array of `short int`, the type you're looking for is `short int*`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude since the method is inside a library I cant change it, so I have to pass an argument of type "pointer to array of three short ints". How is is done doesnt matter. If my problem is not solvable, I have a plan B, but it's less performant.

Comment: Consider using std::basic_string_view<short> (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view). This way you won't have to use type conversions so much and you have nicer interface to work with.
Also, don't pass the SomeArray to a function by pointer. Pass it by reference. Like this `void method(SomeArray& a) { /* do stuff */ }`. This way you don't have to do (*a)[idx] everywhere you access its elements.

Comment: @lego IIUC the signature of `method` cannot be changed by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You probably get away with casting the address of `var[1]` to the type of pointer to an array with three elements. It's probably illegal, strictly spoken, because I suppose it violates the strict aliasing rules (typed objects may only be accessed through expressions of compatible types) — but only very slightly ;-)<sup>1</sup>. Semantically there is no problem because the shorts expected in the 3 element array are all there. It will probably work everywhere, strictly spoken as well:

```
$ g++ --version && cat arrpassing.cpp && g++ -Wall -o arrpassing -O3 arrpassing.cpp && ./arrpassing
g++ (GCC) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef short int SomeArray[3];

void method(SomeArray* arr)
{
  int i=0;
  for(auto el: *arr) cout << "arr[" << i++ << "]: " << el << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  short arr5[5] = { 0,1,2,3,4 };

  method((SomeArray *)(arr5+1));

  return 0;
}

arr[0]: 1
arr[1]: 2
arr[2]: 3
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>It's really a borderline issue. Obviously, you can access individual elements of an array through simple pointers to type; and the C++ standard regards single objects as arrays of size 1 in certain situations, so you could make a case that it is OK to access memory of larger arrays through "sub-arrays" (of the same element type, of course).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> I need a variable of type SomeArray, whose [0] = var[1], [1] = var[2], [2] = var[3] to pass it to the test() method
>
> But how to convert [a bigger array] into a variable of type `SomeArray` to be an array with 3 elements?

Like this:

```
short big_array[] {0, 1, 2, 4, 5};
SomeArray small_array {
    big_array[1],
    big_array[2],
    big_array[3],
};
method(&small_array);
```

---

However, if you always need a subarray (i.e. always need consecutive elements), then you could avoid copying by changing `method` to simply take a pointer to the first element of the array:

```
void method2(short arr[3]);
```

This way, you can call the function with subarray of any sized array (provided that it has enough elements):

```
short big_array[] {0, 1, 2, 4, 5};
method2(big_array + 1);
```

As a downside, compile time type checking doesn't save us from mistakes, and passing a too small array simply has undefined behaviour.

---

This idea can be expanded and you could support any other (traversable) data structure in addition to arrays, by making `method` a function template, and accept any arbitrary iterator.

Comment: The index in `void method2(short arr[3]);` is ignored, which makes the signature equivalent to  `void method2(short arr[]);` which is just another way of saying `void method2(short *arr);`. Try printing `sizeof(arr)` in your function!

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Indeed. It's just documentation for the user of the function. It implies that passing a pointer to an element with less than 3 successive siblings (counting the pointed element itself) would be a mistake.

Comment: I'm sure it confused Natha -- its intent confused me (because it appears so close to the word "subarray" of which none is in sight ;-)).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider What do you mean by "none is in sight"? An array of length N has N + 1 over 2 sub arrays.

Comment: It does have sub-arrays factually, but you do not produce one: We agree that you produce and pass a pointer to short, without size information. So: Does an array in C++ contain subarrays, grammatically? In other words, is `**(SomeArray *)&big_array` allowed (aliasing big_array's memory through a different array type)?

Comment: (Incidentally, that's what I'm doing in my answer.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I see the confusion. I'm talking about sub arrays as a mathematical / computer sciencey concept - not in relation to the type system of C++. That is, I don't mean to talk about sub objects of array type. Indeed, such array sub objects don't exist here. I'm fairly certain that the cast you suggest (or at least accessing the array through the converted pointer) has undefined behaviour. It could be nice though if if was well defined.

Comment: Yeah, Algol68, Fortran77 and Ada all have sub-arrays as slices; Algol68 can even produce column aliases :-).